# C++ update framework for Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, frameworks

I've written a C++ application primarily for Ubuntu Linux and am looking for an automatic update framework, i.e. I want to the application to check for updates and download them when available and authenticated.

I have been unable to find a framework for C++ on Linux. I have found TUF, but tha is for python, and Sparkle is for OSX. So does anyone know of a framework that would be able to help me?

Comment: Don't. The package manager takes care of the updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are *only* interested in providing this application for Ubuntu, look at the PPA functionality of LaunchPad:  https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

This allows you to create your own APT repository.
Any user that adds your repo to his system will automatically get all updates you push through your repo.

Of course, other Linux distributions have similar setups, e.g. Opensuse has OBS.
But that was not part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Notary is an implementation of The Update Framework (TUF) written in Go. It is hosted by the Cloud Native Computing Foundation and is a core component of Docker.

https://github.com/theupdateframework/notary